# Get Tap Gesture to link back to the First View without back button?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

Currently I have a Master View and a Detail View.  In the detail there is an image I added a TapGestureRecognizer to. And then on the TapGestureRecognizer I added a segue push back to the master view. The problem is in the simulator when I click on the image it takes me to the Master View but the back button in the navigator item says the name of the detail view.

I want the tap gesture to link back to the first master view. Instead of linking to a master view with a back button. How could I do this though? I think it has to do with prepare Segue.

Any Help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a couple hours but I saw I didnt need a segue but just had to handle the tap gesture in my class:

```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    }

    - (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        //The event handling method
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pop the view controller. Call the method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and it will go back to the previous view.